# migrate data from SonarQube v4.5.6 to v7.1

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, migration

I am setting up a new SonarQube server, running version 7.1. The old one still runs 4.5.6. The old one runs on MySQL 5.1, the new one on MySQL 5.7. The new SonarQube version does not support MySQL 5.1.

Is there a way to migrate the "old" data to the new server?

I doubt it, as the new DB has more tables, and the structure of the tables is also different...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can always do a mysql dump and import.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the path explained in the [Upgrading doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) => Migrate to SonarQube 5.6, then 6.7, then 7.1.